# Show that if the unit ball of $L_1(\mu)$ admits an extreme point, then $\mu$ admits an atom of finite measure.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is a question from Conway's Functional Analysis.

Let $(X, \mathscr{\Omega}, \mu)$ be a measure space.

Show that if the unit ball of $L_1(\mu)$ admits an extreme point, then $\mu$ admits an atom $A \subseteq X$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$.

We define an atom as a set $A \in \mathscr{\Omega}$ such that $\mu(A) > 0$ and for any $B \subseteq A$, we have $\mu(B) = \mu(A)$ or $\mu(B) = 0$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Bojack, what are your thoughts

Comment: I believe we can take an extreme point $f \in L_1(\mu)$ and then show that the set $\{x : f(x) \neq 0\}$ is an atom.